# Nested queries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to combine 2 queries using a nested query.
The first one is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( de.MCH_CODE) AS Mach, md.MAT_CODE as ShortenCode, de.TIME as start_time
FROM table1 AS de
JOIN table1table2 AS md
ON de.subcode= md.subcode
WHERE de.ev = '123' AND de.time > '2017-11-14 07:00' and de.side = 'R' AND de.end IS NULL AND de.Subcat = 'STOP'
ORDER BY de.time
```

Which generates the result

```
Mach  ShortenCode  Tme  
Mach1   451         2017-12-25 08:25
Mach2   854         2017-12-25 08:25
```

So 451 is on Mach1. The tricky part is that for ShortenCode  i would like to show the previous Mach that it was on.
It would be something like:

```
SELECT distinct de.MCH_CODE FROM table1 AS de
join table2 as md
ON de.subcode = md.subcode 
WHERE de.ShortenCode = 'the ones displayed in the first query'
```

How can I subquery to get:

```
Mach  ShortenCode  Tme                 Mach(Previous)    
Mach1   451         2017-12-25 08:25   Mach4
Mach2   854         2017-12-25 08:25   Mach5
```

Basily Mach column has Mach1, Mach2 and also Mach4 and Mach5.
I've tried this but with no success:

```
SELECT t1.Mach, t1.ShortenCode, t1.start_time, t2.PreviousMach
    FROM( SELECT DISTINCT( de.MCH_CODE) AS Mach, md.MAT_CODE as ShortenCode, de.TIME as start_time, mch_
            FROM table1 AS de
            JOIN table1table2 AS md
            ON de.subcode= md.subcode
            WHERE de.ev = '123' AND de.time > '2017-11-14 07:00' and de.side = 'R' AND de.end IS NULL AND de.Subcat = 'STOP'
            ORDER BY de.time
    ) t1
    join
        ( SELECT distinct de.MCH_CODE FROM table1 AS de
                join table2 as md
                ON de.subcode = md.subcode 
                WHERE de.ShortenCode = t1.ShortenCode
        ) t2
```

If you have any suggestions I would appreciate very much

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not** a function (on a column). It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant parentheses, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT de.MCH_CODE AS Mach, ...`.

Comment: Check, Thanks @jarlh . What about the logic of the query? Is this the correct way of combining the two of them

Comment: i hate reverse engineering queries. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try getting the subquery in the SELECT part like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT( de.MCH_CODE) AS Mach, md.MAT_CODE as ShortenCode, de.TIME as 
start_time,
(SELECT dee.MCH_CODE FROM table1 AS dee JOIN table1table2 AS mdd
ON dee.subcode= mdd.subcodewhere md.MAT_CODE = mdd.MAT_CODE and 
dee.MCH_CODE < de.MCH_CODE order by dee.MCH_CODE DESC LIMIT 1) as prevMach
FROM table1 AS de
JOIN table1table2 AS md
ON de.subcode= md.subcode
WHERE de.ev = '123' AND de.time > '2017-11-14 07:00' and de.side = 'R' 
AND de.end IS NULL AND de.Subcat = 'STOP'
ORDER BY de.time
```

although I am guessing that depending on the indexing and the amount of data it could take long to compute.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query to get your answer.

```
SELECT distinct de.MCH_CODE 
FROM table1 AS de 
join table2 as md ON de.subcode = md.subcode WHERE de.ShortenCode 
in
(
    select Table2.ShortenCode from
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT de.MCH_CODE AS Mach, 
                       md.MAT_CODE as ShortenCode, 
                       de.TIME as start_time
       FROM table1 AS de 
       JOIN table1table2 AS md ON de.subcode= md.subcode
       WHERE de.ev = '123' AND de.time > '2017-11-14 07:00' and de.side = 'R' AND de.end IS NULL AND de.Subcat = 'STOP'
       ORDER BY de.time
    ) Table2
)
```